# solr nested multivalued fields

Tags: solr, indexing, field, multivalue

I would like to produce the following result in a Solr search result but not sure it is possible to do? (Using Solr 3.6)

```
<doc>
   <arr name="groups">
      <lst>
         <str name="firstName">John</str>
         <str name="lastName">Darby</str>
      </lst>
      <lst>
         <str name="firstName">Sue</str>
         <str name="lastName">Berger</str>
      </lst>
   </arr>
</doc>
```

However, i cant seem to manage getting this Tree like structre in my results. At best I can get something to look like the following which is not even close:

```
<doc>
   <arr name="groups">
      <str>John</str>
      <str>Darby</str>
      <str>Sue</str>
      <str>Berger</str>
   </arr>
</doc>
```

There are two problem here. Firstly, I cannot seem to  "group" these people into a meaningful  tag structure as per the top example. Second, I cant for the life of me get the  tags to display an attribute name like "lastName" or "firstName" when inside an array?

In my project I am pulling this data using a DIH and from the example above one can see that this is a on-to-many relationship between groups and users.

I really would appreciate it is someone has some suggestions or alternative thoughts.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of Your schema and exact search criteria used?  That may help.

Comment: Jerome has asked this in a lucene forum: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/solr-nested-multivalued-fields-td3989114.html